# vlc/libvlc - how to get a reference to a custom vlc module

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc

I am creating android application that uses `libvlc` to play a video.
Since vlc/libvlc doesnt have any kind of event/callback for subtitles i have created my own `text renderer` module in `modules/text_rendere/spucallback`

Module compiles, but i have two problems.:

1. I dont see any log messages from this module
2. How can i use this module from libvlc

callback.h

```
typedef void (*spu_cb_t)(text_segment_t *p_segment);

struct spu_cb_t {
    spu_cb_t cb;
};

struct spu_cb_t *callback;
```

callback.c

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
# include "config.h"
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
/* VLC core API headers */
#include <vlc_common.h>
#include <vlc_plugin.h>
#include <vlc_interface.h>
#include <vlc_filter.h>
#include "callback.h"

static int Open(vlc_object_t *);
static void Close(vlc_object_t *);
static int RenderText(filter_t *,
                  subpicture_region_t *p_region_out,
                  subpicture_region_t *p_region_in,
                  const vlc_fourcc_t *p_chroma_list);

/* Module descriptor */
vlc_module_begin()
    set_shortname(N_("SPU Callback "))
    set_description(N_("SPU Callback module"))
    set_capability("text renderer", 0)
    set_callbacks(Open, Close)
    set_category(CAT_VIDEO)
vlc_module_end ()

static int Open(vlc_object_t *p_this)
{
    filter_t *p_filter = (filter_t *)p_this;
    p_filter->pf_render = RenderText;

    printf("spucallback:Open");

    callback = (spu_cb_t*) malloc(sizeof(spu_cb_t));
    if (!callback)
        goto error;

    return VLC_SUCCESS;  

error:
    free(callback);
    return VLC_EGENERIC; 
}

static void Close(vlc_object_t *p_this)
{
    printf("spucallback:Close");

    free(callback->cb);
    free(callback);
}

static int RenderText(filter_t *p_filter,
    subpicture_region_t *p_region_out,
    subpicture_region_t *p_region_in,
    const vlc_fourcc_t *p_chroma_list)
{
    text_segment_t *p_segment = p_region_in->p_text;
    callback->cb(p_segment);
    printf("spucallback:RenderText");

    return VLC_SUCCESS;
}
```

Code is not yet finished obviously

This log messages might be related:

```
[e41bfa2c] core spu text: looking for text renderer module matching "spucallback": 1 candidates
[e41bfa2c] core spu text: no suitable access module for `file:///vendor/etc/fallback_fonts.xml'
[e41bfa2c] core spu text: using text renderer module "freetype"
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure you module is loading?
2. You can't. You have to add your plugin specific API to libvlc.

Comment: @RSATom I m not sure, i have updated my question with possibly related log message. And for the other part, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: As I know libvlc for android use static linked plugins, so if you want use your own plugin there - you have to add your plugin to libvlc build system, to get it linked to libvlcjni.so

Comment: @RSATom How exactly do i do that?

Comment: Sorry, don't know answer for this question... Just know you will have to do it.